# How to chain a variable number of promises in Q, in order?

Tags: node.js, promise, q

> I have seen [Chaining an arbitrary number of promises in Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976573/chaining-an-arbitrary-number-of-promises-in-q) ; my question is different.

How can I make a variable number of calls, each of which returns asynchronously, in order?
The scenario is a set of HTTP requests, the number and type of which is determined by the results of the first HTTP request.

I'd like to do this simply.

I have also seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17452570/48082%20this%20answer) which suggests something like this:

```
var q = require('q'),
    itemsToProcess =  ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];

function getDeferredResult(prevResult) {
  return (function (someResult) {
    var deferred = q.defer();
    // any async function (setTimeout for now will do, $.ajax() later)
    setTimeout(function () {
      var nextResult = (someResult || "Initial_Blank_Value ") + ".." + itemsToProcess[0];
      itemsToProcess = itemsToProcess.splice(1);
      console.log("tick", nextResult, "Array:", itemsToProcess);
      deferred.resolve(nextResult);
    }, 600);

    return deferred.promise;
  }(prevResult));
}

var chain = q.resolve("start");
for (var i = itemsToProcess.length; i > 0; i--) {
    chain = chain.then(getDeferredResult);
}
```

...but it seems awkward to loop through the itemsToProcess in that way.  Or to define a new function called "loop" that abstracts the recursion.  What's a better way?

Comment: This seems not to be a variable number of promises, but a set number depending on the length of the array. There are cases where you actually have a variable number and I'm not sure that the `reduce` method works for those.

Comment: https://github.com/kriskowal/q#sequences would be the official reference

Answer (score 76, accepted):

There's a nice clean way to to this with [`[].reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```
var chain = itemsToProcess.reduce(function (previous, item) {
    return previous.then(function (previousValue) {
        // do what you want with previous value
        // return your async operation
        return Q.delay(100);
    })
}, Q.resolve(/* set the first "previousValue" here */));

chain.then(function (lastResult) {
    // ...
});
```

[`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) iterates through the array, passing in the returned value of the previous iteration. In this case you're returning promises, and so each time you are chaining a `then`. You provide an initial promise (as you did with `q.resolve("start")`) to kick things off.

At first it can take a while to wrap your head around what's going on here but if you take a moment to work through it then it's an easy pattern to use anywhere, without having to set up any machinery.

Comment: sweet! and very handy!

Comment: What happens in the event a promise is rejected? Or, at least, how would we handle that case?

Comment: @naivedeveloper If a step rejects then the following steps won't be executed and `chain` will also be rejected, so you can just catch this case with `chain.catch`.

Comment: Very nice solution. Thanks!

Comment: This is perfect and melted my brain until I saw it run. Then it made perfect sense.

Comment: This is pretty mind bending at first, as @manu said, but man, is it cool when you wrap your brain around it. Saved me with a tricky problem at work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I like this way better:

```
var q = require('q'),
    itemsToProcess =  ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];

function getDeferredResult(a) {
  return (function (items) {
    var deferred;

    // end
    if (items.length === 0) {
      return q.resolve(true);
    }

    deferred = q.defer();

    // any async function (setTimeout for now will do, $.ajax() later)
    setTimeout(function () {
      var a = items[0];
      console.log(a);
      // pop one item off the array of workitems
      deferred.resolve(items.splice(1));
    }, 600);

    return deferred.promise.then(getDeferredResult);
  }(a));
}

q.resolve(itemsToProcess)
  .then(getDeferredResult);
```

The key here is to call `.then()` on the `deferred.promise` with a spliced version of the array of workitems.  This `then` gets run after the initial deferred promise resolves, which is in the fn for the setTimeout.  In a more realistic scenario, the deferred promise would get resolved in the http client callback.

The initial `q.resolve(itemsToProcess)` kicks things off by passing in the work items to the first call of the work fn.

I added this in hopes it would help others.

Comment: It's probably more normal to build a `.then()` chain in a loop as per your first example rather than go recursive. Whichever way you choose, it may be important not to destroy the original array. If so, then you can get the promises (and their callbacks) to work with an increasing index value that operates on the original unsullied array.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a concept of a state machine defined with `Q`.

Suppose you have the HTTP function defined, so it returns a `Q` promise object:

```
var Q_http = function (url, options) {
  return Q.when($.ajax(url, options));
}
```

You can define a recursive function `nextState` as following:

```
var states = [...]; // an array of states in the system.

// this is a state machine to control what url to get data from
// at the current state 
function nextState(current) {
  if (is_terminal_state(current))
    return Q(true);

  return Q_http(current.url, current.data).then(function (result) {
    var next = process(current, result);
    return nextState(next);
  });
}
```

Where `function process(current, result)` is a function to find out what the next step would be according to the `current` state and the `result` from the HTTP call.

When you use it, use it like:

```
nextState(initial).then(function () {
  // all requests are successful.
}, function (reason) {
  // for some unexpected reason the request sequence fails in the middle.
});
```

Comment: This makes a lot more sense to me than the other while-loop solutions out there. It's also easier to adapt to other Promise libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I propose another solutions, which looks easier to understand to me.
You do the same as you would when chaining promises directly: 
`promise.then(doSomethingFunction).then(doAnotherThingFunction);`

If we put that into a loop, we get this:

```
var chain = Q.when();
for(...) {
  chain = chain.then(functionToCall.bind(this, arg1, arg2));
};
chain.then(function() {
    console.log("whole chain resolved");
});


var functionToCall = function(arg1, arg2, resultFromPreviousPromise) {
}
```

We use [function currying](https://phuu.net/2012/11/16/useful-js-currying-and-bind.html) to use multiple arguments. In our example
`functionToCall.bind(this, arg1, arg2)` will return a function with one argument: `functionToCall(resultFromPreviousPromise)`
You do not need to use the result from the previous promise.