# Angular JS: processing promises in order (without chaining)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is similar to question [17757654](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757654/how-to-chain-a-variable-number-of-promises-in-q-in-order), but without chaining.

Background: 
I have a very chatty API which brings back some JSON every key press, and sometimes these requests come back in the wrong order (with very fast key presses). Chaining promises seems like a reasonable solution, but I was wondering if there is a nice way to solve this without chaining? (and without knowing any details about the request/message)

I've written an example using timeouts here: http://jsfiddle.net/zakGh/

and below,

```js
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);
myModule.factory('HelloWorld', function ($q, $timeout) {

    var getSlowFirstMessage = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $timeout(function () {
            deferred.resolve('Slow First Message');
        }, 2000);

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    var getFastSecondMessage = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $timeout(function () {
            deferred.resolve('Fast Second Message');
        }, 1000);

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    return {
        getSlowFirstMessage: getSlowFirstMessage,
        getFastSecondMessage: getFastSecondMessage
    };

});

myModule.controller('HelloCtrl', function ($scope, HelloWorld) {

    $scope.messages = [];

    HelloWorld.getSlowFirstMessage().then(function (message) {
        $scope.messages.push(message);
    });

    HelloWorld.getFastSecondMessage().then(function (message) {
        $scope.messages.push(message);
    });

});

<body ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="HelloCtrl">
     <h1>Messages</h1>

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="message in messages">{{message}}</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried throttling the messages to not trigger so quickly, maybe every 250ms or something on keypresses?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish, but is this kind of what you're thinking? http://jsfiddle.net/zakGh/1/

Comment: @Lukas the problem with all is that it waits for them all to be complete. Refer to my answer for how to use queue.

Comment: @JonathanRowny Well, the drawback to using queue is that it executes everything in series. While mine waits for them all to complete, it does it in parallel, so it actually ends up being quicker than doing them in series.

Comment: @Lukas true, but in his situation when you're adding promises as you type, you'd need some sort of queue, you won't know how many promises you have ahead of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use Queue from the async library found here: https://github.com/caolan/async#queue

If you set the concurrency to 1, it just does it all in series. Check out the example

```
myModule.controller('HelloCtrl', function ($scope, HelloWorld, $timeout) {

$scope.messages = [];   

var q = async.queue(function (task, callback) {
    task().then(function(message){
        $timeout(function(){
            $scope.messages.push(message); 
            callback();
        });
    });
}, 1);


// assign a callback
q.drain = function() {
    console.log('all items have been processed');
}

// add some items to the queue

q.push(HelloWorld.getSlowFirstMessage, function (err) {
   console.log('finished processing slow');
});
q.push(HelloWorld.getFastSecondMessage, function (err) {
   console.log('finished processing fast');
});

});
```

Here's the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zakGh/4/

Comment: Cool thanks, I've given you the correct answer. But, do you know if both messages could be executed in async, then come back ordered within the callback? (it would appear as if both messages came back at once) Or is this kinda abusing javascript?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure if queue will return them in order if you up the concurrency, but I would assume not. You could certainly write your own code based on Async which behaves exactly as you describe by placing results in an array and only popping them out if the right order is achieved. Maybe that already exists and I just don't know about it.