# Executing asynchronous functions serially with a delay

Tags: javascript, parameters, setinterval, delayed-execution

originally I have something like this (ads is an array) :

```
for (var i = 0; i < ads.length; i++) {
    asynchMeth(ad[i]);
}
```

asyncMeth is an asynchronous method that calls the server (I cannot make it synchronous). But I would like that asynchMeth(ad[i]) will start 3second after asynchMeth(ad[i-1]) has finished. The following doesn't work but it gives an idea on what I am looking for :

```
    isWorking = false; //Will be set to true whenever asyncMeth starts, to false when it ends.

     var i = 0;
     var timer = setInterval(3000, function() {
       if(!isWorking){
          if(i < ads.length){
               asyncMeth(ads[i]);
               i++;
           }
           else{
                clearInterval(timer);
           }
        }
    });
```

How to work with setInterval when we are calling function with different/dynamic parameters ?

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you want... do you want async(ad[1]) to be fired as soon as async(ad[0]) is finished, or do you want it to be fired one second after the first one is launched?

Comment: "I cannot make it synchronous" – but that is exactly what you're trying to do. What is `asyncMethod` doing?

Comment: Are you sure that the solution is not just swapping the parameters of setInterval? (compare http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Comment: It is a set of processes and each take time, If I will do that the synchronous way the interface on browser will be grayed out. I am not sure if the use of "setInterval" is a solution.

Comment: @minchiya Take a look at my solution to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would first add a callback to `asyncMeth` that is called whenever the function has finished doing whatever it is doing. Otherwise there is no way to know if `asyncMeth` has finished its work. In your example what you have isn't the same as what you want! You want `ads[i]` to process 3 seconds after `ads[i - 1]` has *finished*. Instead, what you have is code to start processing `ads[i]` 3 seconds after `ads[i - 1]` has *started processing*. With a callback to `asyncMeth`, you can then do this:

```
(function work(i) {
    if(i < ads.length) {
        asyncMeth(ads[i], function() {
            work(++i);
        });
    }
}(0);
```

Here you have a self-invoked function that initially accepts a parameter value of `0`. This value is assigned to the parameter `i`. If `i` is lesser than `ads.length`, it means that we still have items to process. So it calls `asyncMeth` with `ads[i]` as a parameter.

But then we also provide a callback. In this callback we tell the callback to call `work` with the incremented the value of `i`. This means that `work` will start processing the next item.

So now you can asynchronously-process each item one after the other until `i` becomes equal to `ads.length`, at which point you have processed all the items.

**EDIT**

I noticed that you mentioned that you want a 3-second delay. For that you can do this:

```
(function work(i) {
    if(i < ads.length) {
        asyncMeth(ads[i], function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                work(++i);
            }, 3000);
        });
    }
}(0);
```

The only difference here is that the next iteration happens 3 seconds after the last one has completed.

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT, there are two answers to be given here: the one you're asking for, and the one you need. I'll give both in case someone else stumbles upon this answer from Google.

**What you should do**

It looks like you're trying to make a bunch of asynchronous calls happen in sequence, and guessing that they'll come back in about three seconds. Of course, if that turns out not to be an accurate guess, you're going to have problems, so what you really want is a function that will be triggered at the instant that the request comes back.

There are two ways to do this - either continuation-passing style (aka callback hell), or with promises. The former is easier conceptually, but gets ugly in a hurry:

```
$http('url', function (data) {
  //this function is called when the AJAX request comes back
  //do something with data
  $http('url2', function (data) {
     //do something with second piece of data after request 2 loads
  })
})
```

This gets to be a real mess when you need an arbitrary number. My preferred solution is a recursive higher-order function, such as the following, although it is possible to do it iteratively:

```
var launch = function f (i) {
  return function (data) {
    //do something with data

    if (i <= urls.length - 1)
      $http(urls[i+1], f(i+1))
  }
}

//manually trigger the first one
launch(0)()
```

The cleaner way is with promises. There are hundreds of tutorials on how to use promises to clean up async code, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757654/how-to-chain-a-variable-number-of-promises-in-q-in-order) is an example of how to do it for a variable number of requests.

**What you asked**

If you really want to just launch a bunch of timeouts with different arguments, the trick is to close over each one to cache the value of `i`. If you do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    //i is 20 by the time this runs...
  }, 1000)
}
```

then all 20 invocations of the function will see `i` as 20, which is probably not what you wanted.

The solution is this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  setTimeout((function (j) {
    //do something with j, which is a copy of the value of i for this iteration
  })(i), 1000)
}
```

The reason this works is that explicitly-passed primitive function arguments (i.e. numbers) are passed by value, while "passing" a variable by closure (which is what's happening in the broken example) passes by reference, even for primitives.