# How to run a promise-then chain using map or reduce on an arbitrary number of chain elements?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, mapreduce, promise, rsvp-promise

I'm stuck on the following:

A script is returning an arbitrary number `n` or array, like this:

```
[["a"], ["b"], ["c"], ["d"]]
```

I need to loop over the arrays using promise `then()`, but as I don't know how many elements there will be, I have ended up doing this:

```
  var bundle_list = [["a"], ["b"], ["c"], ["d"]];

  var x = bundle_list.reduce(function(current, next) {
  console.log(current);

  // requestBundle will also return a promise
  return requestBundle(current)
    .then(function(bundle_response) {
      // do foo
      console.log("CALLING NEXT")
      console.log(next);
      return RSVP.resolve(next);
    });
})

x.then(function(last_response) {
  return console.log("DONE")
});
```

My problem is that my `reduce/map` both trigger all iterations before my async code is run, so I'm getting 3x the `current` console followed by the `done` console. So all my map "loop" run instantly, with the results clocking in a little (too) later...

I'm using this [RSVP](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js) implementation, but it's A+ so should not be a problem. I have been trying to work along the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757654/how-to-chain-a-variable-number-of-promises-in-q-in-order), but I cannot get it to work properly.

**Question:**
Is it possible to create a "then-chain" with an arbitrary number of `then` statements. If so, some pointers are appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A for (or forEach) loop should do:

```
var queue = RSVP.Promise.resolve(); // in ES6 or BB, just Promise.resolve();

bundle_list.forEach(function(el){
    queue = queue.then(function(res){
        console.log("Calling async func for", el);
        return requestBundle(el);
    });
});

queue.then(function(lastResponse){
    console.log("Done!");
});
```

Comment: nice. Did not even think of forEach... Works like a charm.

Comment: you could add that in order to call request like this: `request(["foo", "bar"]).then(function(module_arr) {...})` the last queue part should return a `RSVP.resolve` as well.

Comment: Perfect answer! I needed this for firebase mixed queries and it works awesome.