# Javascript Angular: how to chain unknown number of promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I'm writing an Angular.js service to pull some `JSON` feeds. Initially, the service does not know which/how many resources to request; they are dependent on ids returned by a another request.

I'm having a headache chaining the `$http` service requests together.  Is there a commonly used pattern to do this?

I've tried the `Array.reduce` technique suggested on another thread, but had problems syncing the ids and the requested data.

This is what I have so far. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
aService.factory('dummy', function($http){
    // Dummy resources.
    var resources = [   
      'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js',
      'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js',
      'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js'
    ];
    return {
        data: function(callback){

            var jquerySources = []

            var promiseChain = $http({method: 'GET', url: resources[0]});
            var l = resources.length
            for (var i = 1; i < l; i++ ){
                promiseChain.then(function(data){

                    jquerySources.push({
                        url: resources[i],
                        source: data
                    });

                    promise_chain = $http({method: 'GET', url: resources[i]});
                    if (i === l){
                        return callback(jquerySources);
                    }
               });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Thankyou.

Comment: Do you actually need to load each resource in turn? If not, can you not just fire off multiple requests and then wait for all the promises to be resolved?

Comment: Do you need them to execute sequentially or can they run in parallel?

Comment: If you're considering Promise chaining you should check out async/await. It'll make your life easier

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you would need to do requests **sequentially**, you would create a promise which you could use as the head of your chain. Then, you could chain $http calls up to that head and resolve the head promise:

```
aService.factory('seq', function($http, $q){
    // Dummy resources.
    var resources = [   
      'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js',
      'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js',
      'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js'
    ];
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var resourcePromise = deferred.promise;
    var res = [];
    angular.forEach(resources, function(resource){
      return resourcePromise.then(function(){
        return $http({ method: 'GET', url: resource });
      }).then(function(data){
        res.push({res: resource, data : data});
      });
    });

    deferred.resolve();

    return {
        getResource: resourcePromise.then(function(){
          return res;
        })
    };
});
```

but if requests would be **in parallel** - then it would be simplier solution. Just array of promises and simply call $q.all function for waiting to resolve all promises.

```
aService.factory('par', function($http, $q){
    // Dummy resources.
    var resources = [   
      'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js',
      'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js',
      'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js'
    ];
    var promises = [];
    var res = [];
    angular.forEach(resources, function(resource){
      promises.push(
        $http({ method: 'GET', url: resource }).then(
          function(data){
            res.push({res: resource, data : data});
          })
        );
    });

    return {
        getResource: $q.all(promises).then(function(){
          return res;
        })
    };
});
```

Also note that in both cases we have res array for collecting results of requests.

EDIT:
[Plunker with example](http://plnkr.co/edit/IgPaoUyPfNerHWvIzuRr?p=preview)

Comment: I was just searching for something similar, and this is awesome Oleksii. A bit of a peasant question, but I was then trying to get that data into a controller and having trouble. I can console.log the data out in the $http function in the factory, but not able to get the output in json into a scope var in a controller. Do you have any suggestions on how to best do this?

Comment: Yes, bassically you need to use .then() function after calling a service. I've just added plunker with example to my answer, take a look on it.

Comment: brilliant, thanks so much Oleksii, I really appreciate it. I just upvoted your answer as well. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! If a final step is required after the chaining promises, you can put an additional resourcePromise.then(()=>{ finalWork();}) after.

Comment: I don't think your sequential example is actually sequential.  You would need to re-assign the promise or use reduce().

Answer (score 3):

You can indeed do this with reduce:

```
var chain = resources.reduce(function (sourcesPromise, url) {
    return sourcesPromise.then(function (sources) {
        return $http({method: 'GET', url: url})
        .then(function (data) {
            sources.push({url: url, source: data});

            return sources;
        });
    });
}, $q.when([]));

chain.then(function (sources) {
    // [{url, source}, ...]
});
```

based on [How to chain a variable number of promises in Q, in order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757654/how-to-chain-a-variable-number-of-promises-in-q-in-order/17764496#17764496)

Comment: Here's an excellent article on using reduce for promise chaining: https://css-tricks.com/why-using-reduce-to-sequentially-resolve-promises-works/