# in node.js, how to use bluebird promise with a for-loop

Tags: node.js, for-loop, promise

I'm using bluebird to make my js code synchronous. When in a for-loop, I don't know the syntax to synchronize it.

```
for (i=0; i < rows.length; ++i) {
    var writeBuffer = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(rows[i]))
    fs.appendFileAsync(filename, i + '');
}
fs.appendFileAsync(filename, 'end');
```

I don't know how to make sure that every appendFileAsync takes place in order, and to make sure to append 'end' after the for-loop. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Why are you creating `writeBuffer`?  You don't seem to be using it at all.  Do you mean to be writing it out to the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
rows.reduce(function(previous, item){
  return previous.then(function(){
    return fs.appendFileAsync(filename, item + '\n');
  });
}, Promise.resolve())
.then(function(){
  fs.appendFileAsync(filename, 'end');
});
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17764496/1807881

The idea is to chain the promises for each item in the array so they execute in order. With `reduce` you can grab the previous promise and chain it with the next item in the array using `then`.

Comment: You can avoid the `rows.shift()` (and making the script work with empty arrays as well) by starting the accumulator with `Promise.resolve()` instead of that `first` call

Answer (score 0):

You can use array reduce, but for this situation you might not want to consildate your data before making any fs calls.

With array reduce:

```
  var Promise = require('bluebird');
  var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));

  rows.map(function(row) {
    return new Buffer(JSON.stringify(row));
  }).concat(['end'])
    .reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a.then(function() {
          return fs.appendFileAsync(filename, b);
        })
    }, Promise.resolve(''))
    .then(function(res) {
      // all done here
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      throw err;
    });
```

In my opinion the following would be just fine

```
  var data = rows.map(function(row) {
    return JSON.stringify(row);
  })
  .concat(['end'])
  .join('');

  fs.appendFileAsync(filename, data).then(function(res) {

  });
```

Once you create a promise, its going. Array reduce is a good way to ensure sequential execution. You are essentially building a chain of promises. In your situation it would work, but is it the best call? Thats going to be a fs call for each row and added complexity to the operation.