# How to iterate an array synchronously using lodash, underscore or bluebird

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, lodash, bluebird

I have an array that contains filenames at each index. I want to download those files **one at a time** (synchronously). I know about '`Async`' module. But I want to know whether any functions in `Lodash` or `Underscore` or `Bluebird` library supports this functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use bluebird's [`Promise.mapSeries`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.mapseries.html):

```
var files = [
    'file1',
    'file2'
];

var result = Promise.mapSeries(files, function(file) {
    return downloadFile(file); // << the return must be a promise
});
```

Depending on what you use to download file, you may have to build a promise or not.

**Update 1**

An exemple of a `downloadFile()` function using only nodejs:

```
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

function downloadFile(file) {
    console.time('downloaded in');
    var name = path.basename(file);

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        http.get(file, function (res) {
            res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                fs.appendFileSync(name, chunk);
            });

            res.on('end', function () {
                console.timeEnd('downloaded in');
                resolve(name);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

**Update 2**

As Gorgi Kosev suggested, building a chain of promises using a loop works too:

```
var p = Promise.resolve();
files.forEach(function(file) {
    p = p.then(downloadFile.bind(null, file));
});

p.then(_ => console.log('done'));
```

A chain of promise will get you only the result of the last promise in the chain while `mapSeries()` gives you an array with the result of each promise.

Comment: Without mapSeries: `var downloads = []; for (var p = Promise.pending(), i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) downloads.push(p = p.then(_ => downloadFile(files[i]))); return Promise.all(downloads)`

Comment: @GorgiKosev Your code doesn't work but yes, building a chain of promises would work too. However, using `Promise.all()` here is wrong, you're doing a `Promise.all([p, p, p])`, each file will be downloaded multiple times. I'll update my answer with your suggestion.

Comment: No, thats not correct. A promise represents an operation that was already started, and trying to chain to it multiple times will not cause the same operation to be repeated. Its completely okay to use `Promise.all` just as its okay to attach multiple `then` callbacks to a single promise.

Comment: You're right (object's reference and stuff) but Promise.all is still useless in this case, p.then() is enough.

Comment: Yes, if there is no data to return within the promises, there is no reason to use `Promise.all`

Answer (score 1):

using Bluebird, there is a situation similar to yours with an answer here:
[How to chain a variable number of promises in Q, in order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757654/how-to-chain-a-variable-number-of-promises-in-q-in-order/17764496#17764496)

This seems like a decent solution but in my opinion much less readable and elegant as async.eachSeries(I know you said you don`t want the 'async' solution but maybe you can reconsider.