# How to iterate on array to define the number of promise chains?

Tags: javascript, promise, chai

I want to add chaining to `http.request(url).post(uri)` from `chai` npm module for mocha test feramework.
so I need to add `field` and `attach` promises that is for post as long as the values from an array that will pass as parameters for these chai methods
as follow:

```js
var props = ['name:Sara', 'email:sara@mail.com', 'password:pass'];
var route = '/app/login';
    chaiHttp.request(url).post(route)
    ./* add field promises as much as the array length */
    .then(function(res){
      // do something with this res
    });
```

I do something like this already:

```js
var props = ['name:Sara', 'email:sara@mail.com', 'password:pass'];
var route = '/app/login';
chaiHttp.request(url).post(route).field('name','Sara').field('email','sara@mail.com').then(function(res){
  //do something with response
  });
```

Comment: Have you tried a loop? Or `props.reduce`?

Comment: Yes I tried it also some solutions from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757654/how-to-chain-a-variable-number-of-promises-in-q-in-order

Comment: And it didn't work? Why? Please [edit] your question to include these attempts so we can direct you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The promise returned by `post()` should be the receiver of the `then()` call, but I think you're worried that the intervening `field()` calls will do some harm.

But the hard-coded version you have proves that the field calls propagate their receiver so they can be chained.  Therefore, it's perfectly okay to do something like this:

```
var postPromise = chaiHttp.request(url).post(route);  // this won't start until your code returns from the event loop
['name:Sara', 'email:sara@mail.com', 'password:pass'].forEach(function(pair) {
    var components = pair.split(':');
    postPromise.field(components[0], components[1]);
});
postPromise.then(function(res) {
});
```

Comment: Thanks @danh. Your solution works fine. I am not good in promises :)